# Get a column name from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i this program i get the column name from the database but while try to save it in a array it store the last column name in a array.how to store eash column name in array???

```
$sql="SHOW COLUMNS from itasd2015sem1semester";
if(($result=$conn->query($sql))==true){
    while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
        for($i=0;$i<11;$i++){
            $sub[$i]=$row[0]."\n";
        }
    }
}

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($sub);$i++){
    echo $sub[$i];
}
```

it prints the last column name only??

```
$sql="SHOW COLUMNS from itasd2015sem1semester";
if(($result=$conn->query($sql))==true){
    while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
        for($i=0;$i<11;$i++){
            $sub[$i]=$row[$i]."\n";
        }
    }
}

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($sub);$i++){
    echo $sub[$i];
}
```

it showes an notice..and also it print last column alone.

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test1.php on line 21
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS from itasd2015sem1semester";
if (($result = $conn->query($sql)) == true) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $sub[] = $row[0];
    }
}
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($sub); $i++) {
    echo $sub[$i];
}
```

Comment: it print each column name 11 times

Comment: I don't know how your $result works but try adding below code in your while loop:        if (in_array($row[0], $sub)) {
            continue;
        }

Comment: where i have to add this??

Comment: In your while loop and before '$sub[] = $row[0];'

Answer (score 0):

when i query some of my table called administrator:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `administrator`
```

it returns

[image]

so following code should work

```
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `itasd2015sem1semester`";
$sub = array();
if( ($result = $conn->query($sql)) !== FALSE ) {
    while( $row = $result->fetch_array() ) {
        $sub[] = $row[0]; // get first column ('Field')
    }
}

for( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($sub); $i++ ) {
    echo $sub[$i]. "\n";
}
```